# what is the meaning of this sentence the set n-tuples which have single one and then $n-1$ zeroes form as basis for $X^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given proof taken from [here](https://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/the-algebraic-dual-space/)

I have some confusion in the given below proof marked in red line[image]

**My confusion**: the set n-tuples which have single one  and then  $n-1$ zeroes form as basis  for $X^{**}$

im thinking  like this  $f(e_1)= 1$ and remaining  $f(e_2)=f(e_3)=.....= f(e_n)=0$

then $f(e_1),f(e_2), f(e_3)......f(e_n)$   will form linearly dependent set since $f(e_1) \neq 0$

and it will contradicts the definition of basis

for  basis  $f(e_1),f(e_2), f(e_3)......f(e_n)$ must be linearly independent set i,e $f(e_1)=f(e_2)=f(e_3)=.....= f(e_n)=0$

So  here im confusing

Comment: It should be "form as basis for $X^*$", right? Also, there are $n$ elements in the dual space $f_i \in X^*$, $i=1,..,n$. For each, we have $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Then, the $f_i$ are linearly independent in $X^*$.

Comment: @Cream  the given sentence say $n-1$ zeros  so $f_i$ must be linearly dependent.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. But as I see it, that means we form the dual basis as a tupel $g := \big( g(e_1), g(e_2), .., g(e_n) \big)$. And in this basis, my $f_i$ take the form of $n-1$ zeros and one 1: $f_1 = (1, 0, .., 0)$, $f_2 = (0,1,0,..,0)$ and so on.

Comment: u r right @Cream  thanks u  for clarification